# how to debug Invalid block type

Tags: magento-1.9, error, blocks, exception

I am trying to insert a custom module/block in my home page.  but I am unable to figure out how to call the block from layout file.  can some one explain how to debug the log file.  I can see that my code stuck at 
`_getBlockInstance` but I am unable to figure it out what's wrong.  please help.

LOG

```
    exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type: Mage_Market_Block_Featured' in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/market/app/Mage.php:595
    Stack trace:
    #0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/market/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(495): Mage::throwException('Invalid block t...')
    #1 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/market/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_getBlockInstance('market/featured', Array)
    #2 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/market/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(472): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('market/featured', 'featured_featur...')
    #3 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/market/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(239): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('market/featured', 'featured_featur...')
    #4 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/market/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(205): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
    #5 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/market/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(210): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
    #6 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/market/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
    #7 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/market/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(113): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
    #8 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/market/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(52): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->_renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home')
    #9 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/market/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/controllers/IndexController.php(45): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home')
    #10 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/market/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Cms_IndexController->indexAction()
    #11 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/market/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
    #12 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/market/app/code/community/BalkeTechnologies/StoreMaintenance/Controller/Router/Standard.php(91): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
    #13 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/market/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): BalkeTechnologies_StoreMaintenance_Controller_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
    #14 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/market/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
    #15 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/market/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
    #16 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/market/index.php(105): Mage::run('', 'store')
    #17 {main}
```

local.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <layout version="0.1.0">
        <default>
            <cms_index_index>    
                <reference name="content">    
                    <block type="market/featured" name="featured_featured" as="feature" template="ecom/featured.phtml">
                    </block>
                </reference> 
            </cms_index_index>
        <default>
    </layout>
```

app/code/local/Market/Featured/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Market_Featured>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Market_Featured>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <featured>
                <class>Market_Featured_Block</class>
            </featured>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <featured>
                <class>Market_Featured_Helper</class>
            </featured>
        </helpers>
        <models>
            <featured>
                <class>Market_Featured_Model</class>
            </featured>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

/Block/Featured.php

```
class Market_Featured_Block_Featured extends Mage_Core_Block_Template {
        public function getFeatureProducts() {
            $products = Mage::getModel("featured/featured")­->getFeatureProducts();
            return $products;
  }
}
```

/Model/Featured.php

```
class Market_Featured_Model_Featured extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract {
    public function getFeatureProducts() {
        $feature_products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
        $feature_products->addAttributeToSelect(array(
                                       'image',
                                       'name',
                                       'short_description', 
                       ))
                       ->addFieldToFilter('visibility', array(
                                   Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH,
                                   Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_IN_CATALOG
                       )) //showing just products visible in catalog or both search and catalog
                       ->addFieldToFilter('feature', array('eq' => 1))
                       ->addAttributeToSort('category_id', 'ASC')
                       ->addFinalPrice()
                       ->getSelect()
                       ->where('price_index.final_price < price_index.price')
                       ->limit(3) //we can specify how many products we want to show on this page
    //                 ->order(new Zend_Db_Expr('RAND()')) //in case we would like to sort products randomly
                       ;

        return $feature_products;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm at least 70% certain all you need to do in `local.xml` is change your block type from `market/featured` to `market_featured/featured`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `layout.xml` file you have to write `featured/featured` for block type:

```
<block type="featured/featured" name="featured_featured" as="feature" template="ecom/featured.phtml">
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: type attribute is used to set block class alias. The alias is based on config.xml file of your module.